# Non Readable/Writable Partition Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have an embedded system that contains 2 partitions. When the system boots up it mounts the other partition that it doesn't boot up with. So the root has access to both partitions. Is there anyway to make one partition completely unreadable by root, and only executable?

I know there isn't too much information in this question, but not really sure what other information you may need.

Comment: How can you execute a partition? Or in other words: How can you execute from a partition without reading it? Btw. have a look how read+execution rights work on directories. You can remove the ability to browse a directory while still being able to access files in the directory when knowing their names. You can then only give execution right to the files as well. However, root will always be able to ignore these permission settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The root user will always be able to access this partition (in the end he has access to the raw devices which contain the partitions).